# Converting Text To Emoticons JS

Tags: javascript, chat, emoticons

I found this script: (look down for notes)

```
(function($){   
    $.fn.emotions = function(options){
        $this = $(this);
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.emotions.defaults, options);
        return $this.each(function(i,obj){
            var o = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, $this.data()) : opts;                       
            var x = $(obj);
            // Entites Encode 
            var encoded = [];
            for(i=0; i<o.s.length; i++){
                encoded[i] = String(o.s[i]).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
            }
            for(j=0; j<o.s.length; j++){
                var repls = x.html();
                if(repls.indexOf(o.s[j]) || repls.indexOf(encoded[j])){
                    var imgr = o.a+o.b[j]+"."+o.c;          
                    var rstr = "<img src='"+imgr+"' border='0' />"; 
                    x.html(repls.replace(o.s[j],rstr));
                    x.html(repls.replace(encoded[j],rstr));
                }
            }
        });
    }   
    // Defaults
    $.fn.emotions.defaults = {
        a : "images/emotions/",         // Emotions folder
        b : new Array("angel","colonthree","confused","cry","devil","frown","gasp","glasses","grin","grumpy","heart","kiki","kiss","pacman","smile","squint","sunglasses","tongue","unsure","upset","wink"),            // Emotions Type
        s : new Array("o:)",":3","o.O",":'(","3:)",":(",":O","8)",":D",">:(","<3","^_^",":*",":v",":)","-_-","8|",":p",":/",">:O",";)"),
        c : "gif"                   // Emotions Image format
    };
})(jQuery);


// Notes
// a - icon folder
// b - emotions name array
// c - image format
// x - current selector
// d - type of selector
// o - options
```

This script converts text to emotions. for example, `:)` => [image: smiley]

When I call the function like this:

```
$("#chat").emotions();
```

everything works fine, and `:)` becomes:

```
<img src="images/emotions/smile.png" border="0" alt="">
```

But when I call the function Like this:

```
$("#chat .chatText").emotions();
```

`:)` becomes:

```
<img src="images&lt;img src='images&lt;img src='images&lt;img src='images&lt;img src='images&lt;img src='images&lt;img src='images&lt;img src='images/emotions&lt;img src='images/emotions/snowman.png' border='0' alt='' /&gt;.png' border='0' alt='' /&gt;emotions&lt;img src='images/emotions/watermelon.png' border='0' alt='' /&gt;.png' border='0' alt='' /&gt;emotions/can.png' border='0' alt='' /&gt;emotions/liquor.png' border='0' alt='' /&gt;emotions/blowkiss.png' border='0' alt='' /&gt;emotions&lt;img src='images/emotions/qq.png' border='0' alt='' /&gt;.png' border='0' alt='' /&gt;emotions&lt;img src='images/emotions/beauty.png' border='0' alt='' /&gt;.png' border='0' alt='' /&gt;emotions/smile.png" border="0" alt="">
```

My html looks like this:

```
<div id="chat">
    <div class="message">
        <p>...</p>
        <p class="chatText">
            ...
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
        <p>...</p>
        <p class="chatText">
            ...
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me when I tried it in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/BRAkE/)

```
<div id="chat">
    <div class="message">
        <p>...</p>
        <p class="chatText">
            ... :)
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="message">
        <p>...</p>
        <p class="chatText">
            ... :)
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

(function($){   
    $.fn.emotions = function(options){
        $this = $(this);
        var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.emotions.defaults, options);
        return $this.each(function(i,obj){
            var o = $.meta ? $.extend({}, opts, $this.data()) : opts;                       
            var x = $(obj);
            // Entites Encode 
            var encoded = [];
            for(i=0; i<o.s.length; i++){
                encoded[i] = String(o.s[i]).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
            }
            for(j=0; j<o.s.length; j++){
                var repls = x.html();
                if(repls.indexOf(o.s[j]) || repls.indexOf(encoded[j])){
                    var imgr = o.a+o.b[j]+"."+o.c;          
                    var rstr = "<img src='"+imgr+"' border='0' />"; 
                    x.html(repls.replace(o.s[j],rstr));
                    x.html(repls.replace(encoded[j],rstr));
                }
            }
        });
    }   
    // Defaults
    $.fn.emotions.defaults = {
        a : "http://www.sherv.net/cm/emo/laughing/",         // Emotions folder
        b : ["crying-laughter-smiley-emoticon"],            // Emotions Type
        s : [":)"],
        c : "gif"                   // Emotions Image format
    };
})(jQuery);


// Notes
// a - icon folder
// b - emotions name array
// c - image format
// x - current selector
// d - type of selector
// o - options 


$("#chat .chatText").emotions();
```

Comment: Wired! maybe it happens bacause I load d it with ajax ?
`        success: function(data) {
            $('#chat #messages').html(data);
            $("#chat .chatText").emotions();
        }`

Comment: Can't see why. I can't perform ajax but I have made the code simulate something similar, see the updated jsfiddle, it still works

Comment: What I do see is that you reference #messages in you above command but there is nothing with that id in the html you provided.